# Powershell try-catch VSCode intellisense syntax question

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I haven't seen this syntax before, and it is hard to google this, so I'll ask it here: what does `{1:` mean in

```
try {
    
}
catch {
    {1:<#Do this if a terminating exception happens#>}
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are looking at (part of) a [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the try-catch snippet, resulting in bad text being generated.
It should be:

```
try {
    
}
catch {
    <#Do this if a terminating exception happens#>
}
```

Source:
https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3964